# Not able to see home page after deploying war file in JBOSS 7

Tags: jboss

I have a Struts2 application running successfully in local using Tomcat. I need to deploy the war of that application in JBOSS 7. This is the first time I am trying this.

After putting the war file in the path "E:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments", I can see the message `Deployed "MyApplication.war"` in the console.

But, while hitting the url `http://localhost:9990/<MyApplication>`, I am getting 404 error.
Could you please help to find out where am I doing wrong?

- Note:

I have MyApplication.war.deployed file in the path "E:\jboss-as-
7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments".

I have below configuration in standalone.xml file:

```
<deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" auto-deploy-zipped="true" auto-deploy-exploded="false"/>
```

Comment: Deploy your war file while JBoss is running and see if it will deploy without any errors. Sometimes starting the Jboss with the war already in the deployment folder shows the war as deployed. You might be missing some config tweaking.

Comment: I can see my application in JBOSS Console. And in command line, below lines I can see.
12:14:26,322 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 101) JBAS018210
: Register web context: /Matix
12:14:28,120 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 17) JB
AS018559: Deployed "Matix.war" (runtime-name : "Matix.war")

Comment: If I hit http://localhost:9990/Matix/, nothing comes.

Comment: Have you configured that port 9990 in standalone.xml? Under `<socket-binding-group>`element is your socket-binding for `http` like this `<socket-binding name="http" port="9990"/>`? As you know this element is where you configure your http/https ports. Or just check which port is under this binding and use it instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The port was wrong. It should be 8080. Actually, when I was hitting "localhost:8080/", then JBOSS home page was coming and on clicking the Administration Console link, it was redirected to 9090 port and I thought it is the port where I need to hit for my application. But, as you said, I checked in the configuration file and found the port for http is 8080 and then when I hit the url "localhost:8080/Matix/", I found login page of my application. Thank you very very much.

Comment: You are welcome. Let me answer it and then you could accept the answer just in case other people run across the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated by the other answer, in `JBoss 7.x` the port `9990` by default is for `management-http` and port `8080` for `http`.

The most important thing is to check what port is in the `http` or `https`bindings in the `standalone.xml` configuration file for http and http ssl connection respectively.

You can find that in the section of `<socket-binding-group>` in the `standalone.xml` and you can modify the ports to your taste as long as they are not in use already e.g. I use port `8088` for http.

Then you can use the port stated to call your application, so in your case `http://localhost:8080/<MyApplication>`

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
   ...
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
    ...
</socket-binding-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

port 9990 is used for management-http not for http.

In standalone.xml default value is 8080 for http.

try `http://localhost:8080/<MyApplication>`

double check standalone.xml fot http port.